# Applying multiple filters on files names using glob in Python

Tags: python, regex, file, directory, glob

I would like to apply multiple filters on files names using `glob` library in `python`. I went trough some online sources and can see that using `*` opearation, it's possible to do so. However, my filters are not properly working since I'm trying to apply multiple them together. It is reading more files than it should be.

Suppose my files are stored with date information as follows. I have year, month, and day information as an extension. For instance, the name `my_file_20220101A1835.txt` shows that the file is from January 1st of 2022 and is saved at 6:35pm. If I'd like to get all the files between 2022 and 2023 for the first half of the first six months, I am using the following line.

```
folder_path = "...'
glob.glob(f"{folder_path }/*[2022-2023]**[01-06]**[01-15]*"A"*[01-24]**[00-60]*.pq")
```

Is there a structured way that I can perform this operation efficiently?

Comment: You could use `glob` to grab everything then filter the results by regex.

Comment: This isn't the kind of thing glob patterns are good for. You can't specify ranges of characters like this. `[2022-2023]` is equivalent to `[203]`, and `[01-15]` is equivalent to `[015]`.

Comment: Are the `A`/`B`/`C` just single / constant characters? Are they meaningful in any way, or just separators (e.g: `-`)?

Comment: They are mostly seperators and vary, but I'm only interested in the numbers since they represent year, month etc.

Comment: So the characters in between are always non-numeric? and there may be one-or-more of them?

Comment: Always non-numeric. Numbers are ordered as year-month-day-hour-minute. There cannot be any number between them. Also, I simplified the post. Let's assume that non-numerical value only comes between day and hour information. I have hundreds of thousans of files in the folder. So I have to do this filtering as efficient as possible. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The "*character ranges*" don't work the way you think they do... They operate on single charaters - i.e: `[01-06]` will permit any character matching `0`, `1-0`, `6`... where `1-0` is an invalid (backwards) range.

Additionally, double stars (`**`) are only relevant in some situations - if `recursive=True` it "*will match any files and zero or more directories, subdirectories and symbolic links to directories*", and if `include_hidden=True` it "*will match hidden directories*". [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

---

How about instead - as you're interested in the actual date represented - you parse out the date and match against it. This improves your ability to read and maintain the application - while it's possible to write regex to match this date, it could quickly get difficult to reason about.

```py
import re
from glob import iglob
from datetime import datetime

for fname in iglob('./*.pq'):
  match = re.search(r'/(?P<name>.*)_(?P<date>[0-9]{8})\.(?P<ext>[^\.]+)$', fname)
  if not match:
    # filename format doesn't match what we're after...
    continue

  try:
    date = datetime.strptime(match.groupdict()['date'], '%Y%m%d')
  exception ValueError:
    # the 8 digits we matched don't look like a date...
    continue

  if not (2022 <= date.year <= 2023):
    continue
  if not (1 <= date.month <= 6):
    continue
  if not (1 <= date.day <= 15):
    continue

  # handle file here!
  print(fname)
```

Comment: I prefer not to use ````datetime```` since my string presentation has string characters between the year and month in real. Plus, I have hour and minute info as well. I tried my best to provide an MWE in my post. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: "_since my string presentation has string characters between the year and month in real. Plus, I have hour and minute info as well_" - please provide a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example, this can be easily handled!

Comment: Currently, ```match``` returns ```None``` for each entry in ```iglob```